# A problem concerning three lines in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that we have three different straight lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that  $l_3$ is not in the plane containing $l_1, l_2$ and $l_1$, $l_2$ intersects in exactly one point $P$ and $l_1,l_3$ are in a one plane and $l_2,l_3$ are in a one plane.  How to prove algebraically that $l_3$ intersects $l_1$ and $l_2$ in  the point $P$?

Comment: What if $l_1, l_2, l_3$ are both on a plane and their intersection points make a triangle on the plane?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that $l_3$ is not in the plane containng $l_1,l_2$.